# Bash single-quote elements of array and concatenate using space

Tags: java, arrays, bash, maven

I have an array in Bash that may be empty. I need to convert the array to a single string, placing a single quote around each element, and separating the elements with a single space. For example:

- `()`: `""`
- `("test")`: `"'test'"`
- `("foo bar")`: `"'foo bar'"`
- `("test" "foo bar")`: `"'test' 'foo bar'"`

Assume my array is in `$array`, and I put the result in `$result`. I'm wanting to pass the result as arguments to [Maven `exec:java` `exec.args`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#commandlineArgs), like this:

```bash
array=("test" "foo bar")
result= # TODO
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main" -Dexec.args="$result"
```

This would be equivalent to:

```bash
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main" -Dexec.args="'test' 'foo bar'"
```

Importantly, note that if the array is empty, it would be equivalent to:

```bash
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main" -Dexec.args=""
```

I would have thought that this would have been answered two decades ago—and maybe it has been, but I can't find it. I found [Bash script pass arguments to maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50185415), which has no answer. I found various answers relating to joining with a delimiter, but couldn't find anything that would single-quote each element, join with a delimiter, *and* still produce an empty string if the array is empty.

For example, [Concat array elements with comma and single quote - Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45796762) comes very close:

```bash
array=("test" "foo bar")
joined=$(printf " '%s'" "${array[@]}")
result="${joined:1}"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main" -Dexec.args="$result"
```

But if the array is empty, I get `"''"` when I want `""`. *Update:* I guess I can do an old-fashioned `if` to special-case an empty array. Anyone have anything better?

Comment: you can check array length first `echo ${#array[@]}` or just grep out the empty string `joined=$(printf " '%s'" "${array[@]}" | grep -v "''")`

Comment: May be not better but one-liners are cute lol `result=$([ "${#array[@]}" -gt 0 ] && for a in "${array[@]}"; do joined+=" '$a'";done; echo -n "${joined:1}")
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@Q` operator ([shell parameter expansion - @operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)):

```
array=("test" "foo bar")
result="${array[*]@Q}"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main" -Dexec.args="$result"
```

If both single/double quotes can appear in the array, consider this :

```
array=("foo'bar" 'foo"bar')

mapfile -t array2 < <(perl -e '
    for $_ (@ARGV) {
        $q = /"/ ? "'\''" : q["];
        print "$q$_$q\n";
    }' "${array[@]}")

result="${array2[*]}"
```

This assumes that only one type of quotes can appear in a single item of the array though.

Comment: Amazing!!! This seems to do exactly what I asked for! This is really nice.

Comment: There's a little problem I didn't mention in the question: if I have `("foo'bar")` with a single quote in one of the strings, this produces `"'foo'\''bar'"`, but when substituted in `-Dexec.args="$result"` results in `unbalanced quotes in 'foo'\''bar'`. Any ideas? Besides that tiny corner case, this is an awesome solution.

Comment: Is the error `unbalanced quotes in 'foo'\''bar'` given by `mvn` ? What output do you expect of `("foo'bar")` ?

Comment: Oh, you're right—this is something Maven is producing. Apparently your technique is correctly quoting the `'` on the Bash side, and passing it to Maven—the trick now is to figure out how the Exec Maven Plugin expects us to escape single quotes for that user property, and the [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#commandlineArgs) doesn't give any clues. I'll ask on the Maven user mailing list.

Comment: After further checking at the source code level, it would seem that the [Maven Exec Plugin `exec.args` user property](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineargs) doesn't support quote escaping at all, so no matter how I would escape them in Bash to get them to the plugin (by double-escaping or whatever), the plugin would not understand any escape sequence. So this technique seems to be doing everything it needs to do and is possible to do.

Comment: This technique is just so cool and simple and concise that I'm going to add a bounty to show my appreciation.

Comment: as a bonus question, do you know any way to detect whether each string of the array contains a single or double quote, and use the opposite? i.e. `("foo'bar" "foo\"bar")` would wind up as the characters `"foo'bar" 'foo"bar'`? I imagine that requires quite a bit of Bash work, so I can open a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using [`readarray`](https://helpmanual.io/builtin/readarray/)):

```bash
array=("test" "foo bar")
readarray -t joined < <(printf "'%s'\n" "${array[@]}")
```

If you want the array elements to be shell-escaped, use `%q` instead of `%s`

The result:

```
➜ echo ${joined[@]}
'test' 'foo bar'
```

Another example:

```
➜ array=("foo'bar")
➜ readarray -t joined < <(printf "'%s'\n" "${array[@]}")
➜ echo ${joined[@]}
'foo'bar'
```